# How to interact with a deaf/hard of hearing Uber driver

Tags: cars, disability, service-personnel

A friend of mine told me recently that he ordered an Uber, and while the car was coming, the app informed him that his driver was "deaf or hard of hearing."

[image: screenshot showing Uber's message: "your driver is deaf or hard of hearing."]

He was unsure of the proper etiquette for interacting with a driver with hearing difficulties, and I wasn't sure what to tell him. (He told me that they barely talked at all, but the driver looked in the rear-view mirror whenever there was something to say, apparently to read my friend's lips.)

Is there anything that someone absolutely should/should not do in this situation? Should the passenger try to talk more loudly, or more clearly? Should he try not to talk at all? Other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is really going to depend on the driver. Hopefully your driver will let you know how to communicate with them when you get into the car. I've heard some drivers have pads of paper they may use to communicate questions like if you'd like some water, or would like to pick a specific type of music. They may also let you know if they read lips or if you need to write down any special requests - you can do the latter either on a notepad app on your phone or on paper if you have any. If they *don't* let you know, **[ask them!](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tracy-stine/15-complaints-from-a-lip-reader_b_8612004.html)**

> 12. Don’t assume that all deaf or hard of hearing people can lip read. Ask what their preferred method of communication is first — an interpreter, lip reading, writing back and forth, or even cellphone messages back and forth.

Please note, that over-enunciation or speaking loudly can actually make it more difficult for them to read your lips. There are five great tips for how to be understood when interacting with someone who is lipreading [here](http://deafexpressions.blogspot.com/2015/08/five-tips-to-make-lipreading-easier.html). They go into more detail but the five tips are:

> Tip #1: Beware of facial hair.
>   Tip #2: Don’t stand in front of a window or light.
>   Tip #3: Watch your hands.
>   Tip #4: Speak naturally and at a SLIGHTLY slower pace. Do not over-enunciate.
>   Tip #5: Don’t chew gum or talk with your mouth full.

One thing they note is that even the best lipreaders can't read everything you say, so passing notes may be the better option if you really want to convey something specific.

If you need to say something to them, you can tap them *gently* on the shoulder to get their attention, being cognizant of safety. If they need to avert their eyes to read your lips or a note you're passing their way, they may be distracted from actually driving. As such, unless the driver is actively trying to communicate with you or you need to talk to them, you should follow their lead and let them focus on driving.

Some [other interesting notes](https://eligibility.com/social-security-disability/lip-reading-tips-for-better-communication-with-those-who-are-deaf-or-hard-of-hearing) on lipreading that relate to those who are both deaf or hard of hearing:

> - For people who are hard of hearing and combine lip reading with some sound identification, be aware that background noise can be confusing. Try to find a quiet area, mute a television or a radio and speak up in a clear voice.
> - Some hearing impaired individuals use hearing aids, implant devices and other forms of assistance to augment lip reading. If that’s the case, be courteous and give time for them to put the devices in if requested.
> - Before speaking, make sure you have the person’s attention. Make eye contact before you speak. Tap them on a shoulder if needed. Do not wave your hand in front of a hearing impaired person’s face though--it’s considered rude.

If you use Uber a lot and would like to brighten the day of a hearing impaired driver, consider learning some basic signs in your local sign language (it differs by country, not just language) like "Hi/hello", "Do you read lips?", and "Thank you [for the ride]!".